# Local Drive can't be shared in Docker for a User with no Password

Tags: docker

Docker does not allow to share the local drives for a user with no password set for the windows user. If the windows user having no password policy tries to share the Drive in Docker the popup for giving the username and password comes up but the OK option is greyed out and becomes active only after something is entered in the password box.

[image]

The only solution I can think of is giving a pwd to the user and then provide the same password here.I think there need to be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

After a research I came to a conclusion that Docker does not allow it because of a specific reason,Though I could not digest the reason.

> Docker for Windows volume mounting works is that your entire c-drive is exposed as a network share. The Linux VM that runs Linux containers as part of Docker for Windows then mounts (using Samba) your whole c-drive inside the Linux VM so that linux containers running there can access your c-drive.
>
> As part of the setup, Docker for Windows will create the share network share for the drive (if it's not already there). It would be incredibly unsafe and irresponsible for Docker for Windows to do that if your local user has no password, since Docker for Windows creating that share would make your drives mountable (with no password required) by anyone on your local network.

I hope docker provides a solution for this in the later stage as the issue is still open and Docker team has agreed to provide a better solution.
Please follow the thread for updates : https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/616